# How to create a certificate monitor/watcher in nodeJS/Javascript using setInterval or setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

i am new to javascript/Nodejs,
I want to create a certificate monitor/watcher in javascript.
Here i have written code.

1. I read the certificate file every 5 second using setInterval. [To read certificate information i used certpem package nodejs]
2. I check the condition in monitorCertificateExpiry for expired or not
3. And pass the data to renewCertificate().
4. when ever i get data as "Expired" i will create new certificate file.
   here what is happening is the interval running continuously and many files are generating.

I want to stop the interval and generate only one file and again the interval/watcher should start
How to achieve this.
Please help.

```
let monitorCertificateExpiry = () => {
let now = new Date();
let readData = fs.readFileSync('client.pem','ascii');
let certData = certpem.info(readData);
let data = (certData.issuedAt < now.getTime() && now.getTime() < certData.expiresAt) ? "Valid" : "Expired";
 renewCertificate(data);
}
    
let clearIntrvl= setInterval(monitorCertificateExpiry, 5000);
    
     let renewCertificate = (data) => {
        if (data === "Valid") {
            console.log(data)
        }
        else if (data === "Expired") {
            clearInterval(clearIntrvl);
            issueCertificate();
            console.log("New Certificate Issued");
        }
    }
```